# Angular-Xeditable loading page with all rows in Edit Mode

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I am trying angular-xeditable for the first time and managed to get everything working EXCEPT the page loads with all the table rows in Edit Mode and **I need the default behavior**. (Clicking the 3 cancel buttons after load shows what I am looking to create).

I have a stripped-down plunker (no CRUD methods) that shows what I mean ... [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1jImj2qULqKfQ3pGBzVb?p=preview)

I also created the same using $scope but I would prefer not to use $scope ... [plunker with $scope](http://plnkr.co/edit/qbrQURVV4vcQrlpkq0H4?p=preview)

here is my view:

```
<body ng-controller="DistributorsController as dist">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Distributors</legend>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:22%;">Name</th>
            <th style="width:15%;">Phone</th>
            <th style="width:12%;">Email</th>
            <th style="width:6%;">&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="dis in dist.distributors" ng-dblclick="rowform.$show()">
            <td>
              <span editable-text="dis.name" e-name="name" e-form="rowform" e-style="width:100%;">
                  {{ dis.name || '--' }}
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span editable-text="dis.phone" e-name="phone" e-form="rowform" e-style="width:100%;">
                  {{ dis.phone|phone }}
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span editable-text="dis.email" e-name="email" e-form="rowform" e-style="width:100%;">
                  {{ dis.email || '--' }}
                </span>
            </td>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap">
              <!-- form -->
              <form editable-form="" name="rowform" onbeforesave="dist.saveRecord($data, dis.id)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" shown="inserted == distributor">
                <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" style="color:#006837;"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" style="color: #990000;"></span>
                </button>
              </form>
              <div class="buttons" ng-show="!rowform.$visible">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color: #990000;" ng-click="dist.removeRecord($index, dis.id)"></span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p>
        <a ng-click="dist.insertRecord()" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="color:#006837;"></span>


 Add New</a>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
```

and my controller

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DistributorsController', DistributorsController);

    DistributorsController.$inject = ['$filter'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function DistributorsController($filter) {
      /* jshint validthis: true */
      var vm = this;

      vm.distributors = [
        {id: 1, name: "Jonah's Whale", phone: '3185551212', email: 'jwhale@distributors.org'},
        {id: 2, name: "Paul's Thorn", phone: '5015551212', email: 'pthorne@distributors.org'},
        {id: 3, name: "Lot's Wife", phone: '5045551212', email: 'lwife@distributors.org'}
      ];

    }
})();
```

Comment: @isherwood, can I ask why you edited the Title of my question. It seems to me that being specific (i.e., angular-xeditable) would be helpful given that someone unfamiliar with that technology wouldn't have to even read the question. Rest assured I am not upset; just curious.

Comment: Please use tags in your question title if appropriate. Do not simply append or prepend them at random. I apologize if I misinterpreted your title. Many people just jamb words on the front of theirs. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: understood. since this question is unique to angular-xeditable, I felt it was appropriate in the title. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Doc Says**](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-form)

> To show several editable elements together and submit at once you
>   should wrap them into  tag. The
>   name attribute of form will create variable in scope (normal angular
>   behavior) and editable-form attribute will add a few methods to that
>   variable:

You need to have `ng-form` attribute on each `tr` as other elements are not supported in `table` tag

**Markup**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-form editable-form name="editableForm" 
        ng-repeat="dis in dist.distributors" ng-dblclick="rowform.$show()">
           ...................    
           ..editable input elements here..
           ...................
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[**Wokring Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/A870z5farbH63DGzNEUn?p=preview)

Comment: When I make that edit, I lose my double-click to enter into the edit mode for that row ... unfortunately, that's a show stopper. The specs require a double click (like Excel (yuk!)) rather than an edit button

Comment: I forked the jsFiddle provided with the docs for Table Rows and edited that to enable the double-click and removed the edit button and that's the behavior I need. However, when I edit it to use Controller As, it breaks again. (jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wynnwade/t8w5u9ns/1/)

Comment: @jgravois just curious to know..why you don't want `$scope`?

Comment: I am converting an app from $scope to controller as in preparation for Angular 2.0

Comment: we have an operations app about to go into testing and it is a huge investment so I tried to use the latest and greatest of everything and make it as easy as possible to upgrade when 2.0 is mature.